# Use SDIO pheripheral for quad SPI flash memory

Tags: spi, lcd, sd, stm32f10x, sdio

I am currently doing a project using the STM32F103 micro-controller. The project requires external flash memory to store images and data for later showing on LCD.

The problem I have is that I want to see if I can use the SDIO peripheral on the micro-controller in order to control a Quad SPI flash memory.

Can you use sdio interface with a quad spi flash?

Comment: What is your actual question?  I am sure somebody has tried this before.  If you are having difficulty with a specific design issue please make that clear in the question.

Comment: You can use any of NXP LPC18xx/LPC43xx LPC407x_8x and LPC5410x devices which contain QSPI interface callled SPIFI. You can also directly execute from QSPI with  LPC18xx/LPC43xx LPC407x_8x devices at high speed

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

While most SD cards do also support an SPI operating mode, the converse is not true; the SDIO peripheral on the STM32F103 only supports the SD protocol. It cannot communicate with SPI (or QSPI) devices.

The STM32F103 doesn't support QSPI. You'll need to communicate with your flash device using single-lane SPI, or use another device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you really must interface your QSPI flash with your SDIO microcontroller, it's very likely this is possible.

Check your QSPI flash datasheet; if it allows running in standard SPI mode, as most QSPI-capable devices do allow, you can just run both your flash & the microcontroller in using regular SPI.  If you're just accessing images & data, you should have no problems at all with speed limitations of 1-bit SPI.

By the SDIO specification, if you run in SPI mode, you can only run in 1-bit SPI.  The SDIO specification is conspicuously NOT claiming QSPI compatibility.  4-bits at a time is only possible in SD mode.